# Load Google Map after listview click with jQuery Mobile 1.4.2

Tags: google-maps, listview, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to display a Google Map inside a Single Page JQM project.

The Map needs to be displayed after a listview clik to load a new page with the map.

Model:

```
public class address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Script:

```
// listview events
$(".address").on("click", function ()
{
    var addressId = this.id;
    var addressPage = "#address";

    addressRequest(addressPage, addressId);
});

function addressRequest(page, addressId)
{
    var $page = $(page);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: urlBase + "/GetAddress",
        crossDomain: false,
        beforeSend: function () { $.mobile.loading('show') },
        complete: function () { $.mobile.loading('hide') },
        data: { addressId: addressId },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (address)
        {
            addressBuild(page, address);
            addressLoad(page);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("loadList error!");
        }
    });
}

function addressBuild(page, address)
{
    var $page = $(page);

    $(".ui-content", $page).append('<p>' + address.Name + '</p>');

    var centerLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(address.Latitude, address.Longitude);

    addressLoadMap(centerLatLng);
}

function addressLoad(page)
{
    var $page = $(page);

    $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", $page, { transition: "slide" });
}

function addressLoadMap(latlng)
{
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
}
```

HTML:

Addresses Page Listview:

```
    <!-- page addresses list -->
    <div data-role="page" id="addresses">

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"><h1>mobile</h1></div>

        <div class="ui-content" role="main">
           <li><a href="" id="1" class="address">Company A<span class="ui-li-count">distance: 2.0 km</span></a></li>
        </div>
            <li><a href="" id="2" class="address">Company B<span class="ui-li-count">distance: 3.0 km</span></a></li>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Address Page:

```
    <style>
        #map-canvas {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- page address -->
    <div data-role="page" id="address">

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"><h1>mobile</h1></div>

        <div class="ui-content" role="main">
            <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null
```

Any idea what is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: can you give a link to the page?

Comment: Hi thanks, which page do you refer?

Comment: the page that contains the code above?

Comment: I don't have it online, only in my laptop, what do you need more?

Comment: Add more details....e.g. a jsfiddle-demo. You talk about listview...there is no listview in your code. What does the ajax-response contain?

Comment: I have completed the question with the address's model and the addresses page listview, I can't do a demo because the ajax service is not online yet

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, I was loading the map to soon, the container was not already loaded.

I only can load the map when I show the page:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#address", function ()
{
    addressLoadMap();
});
```